# Keep menu items with onclick active after click

Tags: javascript, css

I have a created a vertical menu. One of the items has `href` attribute and the others have `onclick`. I want each item to be highlighted after being clicked. I have used `a:active` but it only highlights the items only while I am clicking them.

I also used `a:target` but it didn't help me. Is there a way to accomplish this using css or javascript?

```css
.vertical-menu {
    width: 200px;
}

.vertical-menu a {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: black;
    display: block;
    padding: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.vertical-menu a:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.vertical-menu a:active {
    background-color: #FF8F2B;  
}

.vertical-menu a:target {
  background-color: #FF8F2B;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical-menu">
    <a href="http://example.com/">Main</a>
    <a onclick="loadXMLDoc('STATISTICS1.xml')">New Collection</a>
    <a onclick="loadXMLDoc('STATISTICS2.xml')">Intimate Apparel</a>
    <a onclick="loadXMLDoc('STATISTICS3.xml')">Beachwear</a>
</div>
```

Comment: It can be done with JavaScript. You can add a class to the selected item with the css stiles you want when clicking it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This how it should be and how you want it.... The link you click gets background color changed and then if you click other link the previous link goes back to normal and new link gets active...

```js
$('.vertical-menu a').on('click', function() {
$('.vertical-menu a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});

function loadXMLDoc(x){

}
```

```css
.vertical-menu {
    width: 200px;
}

.vertical-menu a {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: black;
    display: block;
    padding: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.vertical-menu a:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.vertical-menu .active {
    background-color: #FF8F2B;  
}

.vertical-menu a:target {
  background-color: #FF8F2B;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vertical-menu">
    <a href="http://example.com/">Main</a>
    <a onclick="loadXMLDoc('STATISTICS1.xml')" href="#new">New Collection</a>
    <a onclick="loadXMLDoc('STATISTICS2.xml')" href="#int">Intimate Apparel</a>
    <a onclick="loadXMLDoc('STATISTICS3.xml')" href="#beach">Beachwear</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you accomplish this using JavaScript and CSS.

Here's an example (using the jQuery library) which sets an active class on the element and has some basic styling applied to the active class:

```
$('.vertical-menu a').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

[Live example](https://jsfiddle.net/yvd9geze/)